# убрать расширение в конце строки

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Я написал в `.htaccess` :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Но у меня (через Chrome/Mozilla/Brave) в URL, при переходе по ссылкам на сайте, прописывается `.php/.html` на конце. Т.е. вместо `example.com/contactus` я вижу `example.com/contactus.php`. Как мне исправить это до конца?

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Запускаем движок заменыэ
RewriteEngine on
# Если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# делаем замену с дописыванием .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```